# title page in book class is not working

Tags: books, book-design

I am recently got introduced to latex and I am using overleaf.
Below is the main.tex

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}

\title{Sequential Decoding Of Lower Limb Movements Using Non-Invasive Brain 
Computer Interface}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-14em}
\vspace{-80pt}
\date{\vspace{-5ex}}
\author{\vspace{-5ex}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
  \input{titlePage.tex}
\end{document}
```

Below is titlePage.tex:

```
\begin{titlepage}
  \maketitle
  \begin{center}
    \text{Thesis\\Submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements 
          of\\BITS F421T Thesis}
    \\[1\baselineskip]
    \text{By}\\
    \medskip
    \textbf{Roshan Sivakumar\\2016A3TS0836H}\\
    \bigskip
    \text{under the supervision of}\\
    \bigskip
    \textbf{Dr.Elahe Abdi \\Mechanical and Aerospace Department \\Monash 
            Univesity, Clayton}\\
    \medskip
    \textbf{Dr. Yan Wong \\Electrical and Computer Engineering Department 
           \\Monash University, Clayton}\\
    \medskip
    \textbf{\&}\\
    \medskip
    \textbf{Dr. BVVSN Prabhakar Rao \\Electrical Engineering Department 
            \\BITS Pilani, Hyderabad}\\
    \\[3\baselineskip]

    \graphicspath{{Images/}}
    \begin{figure}[htp]
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=4cm, height=5cm]{logo}
      \label{fig:bitsLogo}
    \end{figure}

    \medskip
    \textbf{BIRLA INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY AND SCIENCE, PILANI\\HYDERABAD 
            CAMPUS}
  \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

i can't seem to figure out why the titlePage isn't showing up in the output. Only the title is shown though. Also any comments on the commands i used are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The rest of the titlepage do appear but on a 2nd page, because \maketitle would take up a page on its own. Note that you have errors in your code; these would be reported by the red notification balloon next to the "Recompile" button in the Overleaf editor.

Comment: @LianTzeLim It does show an error - "undefined control sequence", but when I put the whole code of the titlePage.tex in the main.tex but in an article class, even with the errors the output was what i expected, so I though it would be fine to ignore these errors. When I used the article class the maketitle did not take a page of its own.

Comment: Yes indeed, because `book` puts `\maketitle` on its own page and `article` does not. If you need `book` then don't use `\maketitle`; insert the title manually with something like `{\huge\makeatletter\@title\makeatother\par}`.

Comment: ohh that makes sense